# String to enum value

Tags: apex, string, enum

How can I convert String to enum value?

```
public enum Season {WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, FALL}
Season season1;
String winterString = 'WINTER';

season1 = winterString; <-- This gives error of course, but is there a way to do it like in java?
```

Comment: Do you think a if else statement will help you?

Comment: Are you trying to cast `Winter` to `Season1`, `Spring` to `Season2`, etc?

Comment: @crmprogdev I have string parameter passed from visualforce, and I recieve string in apex method. So I need to change controller state depending and I would like to use enum to keep code clean. If this is not possible, I can change my code to work with strings instead of enum.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**

The Winter 22 release is adding [**Enum.valueOf**](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_valueOfMethod.htm&type=5&release=234) support.

```
public Enum Season {WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, FALL}

String currentSeasonInput = 'winter';
Season currentSeason = Season.valueOf(currentSeasonInput);
```

---

(Original)

The `String.valueOf` method works great against `Enum` values, so you can build a map as follows:

```
Map<String, Season> seasonValues = new Map<String, Season>();
for (Season enumValue : Season.values())
{
    values.put(String.valueOf(enumValue).toUpperCase(), enumValue);
}
```

I would probably make it `static`. Something like:

```
static Map<String, Season> nameToSeason
{
    get
    {
        // lazy load pattern:
        if (nameToSeason == null)
        {
            //instantiation logic outlined above
        }
        return nameToSeason;
    }
    private set;
}
public static Season getSeason(String name)
{
    return String.isBlank(name) ? null : nameToSeason.get(name.toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: my two cents - anything that is this much effort to implement is just wasting my time

Comment: No doubt about it.

Comment: Why doesn't Apex just have a `Enum.valueOf(String)` just like Java does? Is it so you hit your Apex limits sooner and have to pay them more?

Answer (score 2):

In the above, if using enums, what you omitted is something like this:

```
Season e = Season.WINTER;

Season m(Integer x, Season e) {

    if (e == Season.WINTER) return e;
     //...
}
```

You need to pass an integer to equate `1` with `WINTER`.

Now you could take and create a map of type `map<string,integer>` or of type `map<string,string>` to get key/value pairs such as `('WINTER',1)` or `('SEASON1','WINTER')`. The former could be used to quickly convert your strings for use with your enum class while the latter could be used entirely on their own in place of the enums.

Since I don't know exactly what your use case is, I can't really guide you, but I suspect that a map of some kind might be a better solution for you.

Comment: `Seasong`? Sounds like an object for pirates. :)

Comment: Typos happen to us all, unless of course you're a pirate. :P